# Why does std::apply fail with a generic function?

Tags: c++, c++17

Taken from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply), why does the call to `std::apply(add_generic, ...)` fail to compile? Is there a way to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int add(int first, int second)
{
    return first + second;    
}

template<typename T>
T add_generic(T first, T second)
{
    return first + second;    
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::apply(add, std::make_tuple(1,2)) << '\n';

    // template argument deduction/substitution fails
    std::cout << std::apply(add_generic, std::make_tuple(2.0f,3.0f)) << '\n'; 
}
```

It [fails](https://godbolt.org/g/5Tfgqt) with error:

> [x86-64 gcc 7 (snapshot)] error: no matching function for call to
>   'apply(, std::tuple)' [x86-64 gcc 7 (snapshot)] note:   couldn't deduce template
>   parameter '_Fn'

Comment: Without seeing what errors you get, I would guess it's could be because of not being able to properly deduce the argument type `T`?

Comment: How are you compiling the code? `std::apply` requires `c++17`, does your compiler have `c++17` support?

Comment: `add_generic` isn't a function, it's a template. You can't deduce a type from something that doesn't have a type.

Comment: @Rogus Given the fact that the OP specifically included that only the call involving `add_generic` fails, I think it's safe to say the OP is using a C++17 compiler+library (or something sufficiently close for the purposes of this question).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not new in C++17. Just from the signature of `std::apply`, there is no telling whether you want to pass `add_generic<int>`, `add_generic<float>`, `add_generic<std::string>`, or anything else. Knowing that requires more context (specifically: it requires knowing how `std::apply` is going to invoke it), but that information isn't available at the call site and so cannot be used for template argument deduction.

It's possible to work around that by passing *one* object, and making that one object capable of calling whichever instantiation of `add_generic` is needed:

```
std::cout << std::apply(
    [](auto first, auto second) { return add_generic(first, second); },
    std::make_tuple(2.0f,3.0f)) << '\n';
```