# Perfect forwarding of C++ overloaded and templated functors and its arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

Suppose we have a function that looks like:

```
template <typename F, typename... A>
inline void execute(F&& functor, A&& ... args) {
    std::forward<decltype(functor)>(functor)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}
```

This works for simple non-templated functions. However, I am trying to perfect-forward a templated function(a quite contrived one):

```
namespace detail {

template <typename CodecImpl>
class codec
{
public:
    //
    // Encoding

    // Convenient version, returns an std::string.
    static std::string encode(const uint8_t* binary, size_t binary_size);
    static std::string encode(const char* binary, size_t binary_size);
    ...
};

class base64_rfc4648
{
public:
    template <typename Codec> using codec_impl = stream_codec<Codec, base64_rfc4648>;

    static CPPCODEC_ALWAYS_INLINE constexpr size_t alphabet_size() {
        static_assert(sizeof(base64_rfc4648_alphabet) == 64, "base64 alphabet must have 64 values");
        return sizeof(base64_rfc4648_alphabet);
    }
    static CPPCODEC_ALWAYS_INLINE constexpr char symbol(alphabet_index_t idx)
    {
        return base64_rfc4648_alphabet[idx];
    }
    ...
};

} // namespace detail

using base64_rfc4648 = detail::codec<detail::base64<detail::base64_rfc4648>>;
```

Trying to forward the above:

```
std::string buf("hello world");
execute(base64_rfc4648::encode, buf.c_str(), buf.size());
```

Does not work. Template deduction fails:

> note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'F'

and it also notes:

> No matching function for call to `'execute(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type)'`

How can I fix this?

NOTE: I kept the information short above for readability, but if more info is needed I can add.

Comment: Same issue, essentially, except with a template instead of overloaded function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171323/why-does-stdapply-fail-with-a-generic-function

Comment: If C++ 14 is an option, than the accepted answer there should work for you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with forwarding. You are trying to pass in an overloaded function. That won't work, use a lambda or write a functor.

Comment: I see. I am using a lambda right now. Thank you

Comment: what's up with `decltype(args)` instead of A?

Comment: `decltype(args)` allow you to forward the `T` type if it was an `T` type, and `T&` type if it was `T&` type. (if `args` is type `T`)

Comment: We meant that traditionally, we use `std::forward<F>(functor)(std::forward<A>(args)...);`, `decltype(functor)` is used when forwarding in generic lambda as we don't have named (template) type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `boost::hof` to wrap `base64_rfc4648::encode` in a function object.
`execute(BOOST_HOF_LIFT(base64_rfc4648::encode), buf.c_str(), buf.size());`

Here is the doc of [BOOST_HOF_LIFT](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed

Comment: I am not sure if this will work in C++11. It will compile in C++14 onwards, though.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a MCVE to work on the problem, rather than the code.

So let us have a generic function called `print()` which we want to send to your `execute()`

```
template <typename Arg>
inline void print(Arg const & a) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

where `execute()` is:

```
template <typename F, typename... A>
inline void execute(F&& functor, A&& ... args) {
    std::forward<decltype(functor)>(functor)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}
```

When we try to call `execute(print, 10)` it fails.
The problem is that the `execute()` function doesn't understand which **overload** of `print` are we trying to call.

Now this problem can be solved in 2 ways :

First approach, specify the complete type of the templated function :

```
execute(print<int>, 10);
```

Second approach, create a helper function.
*Every problem can be solved by adding one more layer*.
This helper function will help us deduce the types, before we pass it to `execute()`

```
template <typename Arg>
inline void execute_print(Arg const & a) {
    execute(print<Arg>, a); // we need to specify which overload to be invoked
}
```

And then you can call : `execute_print(20);`

Here is a full working code for your reference(compiled using C++11):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Arg>
inline void print(Arg const & a) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

template <typename F, typename... A>
inline void execute(F&& functor, A&& ... args) {
    std::forward<decltype(functor)>(functor)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}

template <typename Arg>
inline void execute_print(Arg const & a) {
    execute(print<Arg>, a); // we need to specify which overload to be invoked
}

int main() {
    // execute(print, 5); // wont compile
    execute(print<int>, 10);
    execute_print(20);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I should've specified that there are more functions I wanted to call through `execute`. That would mean I would need `execute_foo`, `execute_bar`, etc etc. I have still upvoted your answer though :)

Comment: Agreed. I also wished to make it more generic, but failed to do so. Hence I only posted what was working properly. I faced this problem once, when I wanted to pass my functions to a higher order function, `retry(Func && func, Args && ... args)`. Since, I had a few functions only, I wrote helper functions for them.