# Why does std::apply fail with function template, but not with a lambda expression with explicit template parameter list?

Tags: c++, lambda

In looking at std::apply references from [cpprefrence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) we can see that function templates cannot be passed as callable object of std::apply. Let's consider the following function template:

```
template<typename T>
T add_generic(T first, T second) { return first + second; }
```

So as the function template can't be deduced in std::apply call, we can't use the follwing code:

```
std::apply(add_generic, std::make_pair(2.0f, 3.0f)); // Error: can't deduce the function type
```

Please note that this is not the same question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171323/why-does-stdapply-fail-with-a-generic-function). In that answer, the author writes a lambda expression without explicit template parameters.

```
std::cout << std::apply(
    [](auto first, auto second) { return add_generic(first, second); },
    std::make_tuple(2.0f,3.0f)) << '\n';
```

but as you know in [c++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) you can have lambda expressions with explicit template parameter list. So I tried this feature to the case and surprisingly the compiler did not raise any errors.

```
std::apply([]<typename T>(T first,T second){
    return first+second;
},std::make_pair(2.0,3.0));
```

Why will the compiler be able to deduce type in the last case? Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function *template* is not a function, just like a cookie cutter is not a cookie. C++ templates create new functions for every set of template arguments. And this is precisely why `add_generic` is not a viable argument. It's not a function, it cannot be passed around as a value. To obtain the function, the compiler needs to deduce the template arguments. But it can only do that inside `apply` **after** the callable has been passed. Chicken and egg right there.

Why does a lambda work? Because it's not a plain function either. It produces a hidden object type

```
struct __lambda_at_line_N {
  template<typename T>
  auto operator()(T first, T second) { /* ... */ }
};
```

And passes *that*

```
std::apply(__lambda_at_line_N{},std::make_pair(2.0,3.0));
```

This is an actual object, a value. Its type does not depend on the template argument deduction that needs to happen inside `std::apply` to call `operator()`. That's why it works.

Comment: It makes sense now, thanks