# How to generalize conversion from std::array to struct with raw array member in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, aggregate, stdarray

In C++ I have this struct from C. This code is very old and cannot be modified:

```c
struct Point {
   double coord[3];
};
```

On the other hand, I have this modern function which returns modern `std::array` instead of raw arrays:

```cpp
std::array<double, 3> ComputePoint();
```

Currently, to initialize a `Point` from the returned value, I manually extract each element from the `std::array`:

```cpp
std::array<double, 3> ansArray{ComputePoint()};
Point ans{ansArray[0], ansArray[1], ansArray[2]};
```

This solution is feasible because there are only three coordinates.
Could I templatize it for a general length?
I would like something similar to the opposite conversion: [`std::to_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to do it for any length:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

Point p = std::apply([](auto... args) {
    return Point{args...};
}, computePoint());
```

If you run into this pattern a lot, it could be worth making a convenience function template:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
T make_from_apply(U&& from) {
    return std::apply([]<typename... Args>(Args&&... args) {
        return T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }, std::forward<U>(from));
}

Point p = make_from_apply<Point>(computePoint());
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9nT84jKE4)*

All the `std::forward`ing isn't strictly necessary if `Args` is only going to be fundamental types like `int` and `double`. In that case, you can omit it.

Comment: In case some is asking why to use a lambda function, let me link this question: [Why does std::apply fail with function template, but not with a lambda expression with explicit template parameter list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696245/)

Answer (score 1):

> Could I templatize it for a general length?

Yes, you can use [std::index_sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to generailze this for any length as shown below:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T> constexpr auto make_array(const std::array<T, N> &ref)   
{
    return [&]<std::size_t... Indices>(std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
    {
        return Point{(ref[Indices])...};     
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());   
} 
int main()
{
    std::array<double, 3> ansArray{ComputePoint()};
    Point p = make_array(ansArray);       
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qaEdcfWbn)